# Python pandas dataframe - replace column date format handling NaT

Tags: python, pandas, date, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe with a number of columns that I do some manipulation on.
A number of columns are date type and I am looking to convert dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy.

The issue arises using a apply lambda method to perform the date format conversion. In columns with null values this fails with the error "NaTType does not support strftime".

I tried:

```py
 df['Booking_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Booking_Date'],errors='coerce').apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

and

```py
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['Booking_Date'].isna()==False],errors='coerce').apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the value is NaT using `pandas.isnull()`:

```
df['Booking_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Booking_Date'],errors='coerce').apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.NaT)
```